# Support [tag:tagname] instead of [tagname] in search queries

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-search

Currently, `[tag:tagname]` is used to display and link to the tag `tagname` (commonly used in tag wikis), e.g. "[tagname](/questions/tagged/tagname)". `[tagname]` is used in searches to search for questions with that tag.

This discrepancy in syntax can be confusing. Particularly, if you search for `[tag:tagname]`, it gives you results tagged with `tagtagname`, which is probably not what the user wanted

Comment: I don't see the benefit of this.

Comment: @RobW: It would be a minor fix, enhancing polish by reducing a minor discrepancy in syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Markdown and search syntax are just different. I don't think we should be encouraging users to use improper search syntax by actually *allowing* that syntax while searching. Instead, the search should just look at the tag specified and, if it sees the `tag:` part at the front, strip it out of the search.

So a search for `[tag:tagname]` will actually alter into a search for `[tagname]` and possibly display a notice to the user that their syntax was incorrect and has been changed. Any way, the `tag:` part should *never* be displayed back to the user as a valid search.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple proposed fix:

Support `[tag:tagname]` as well in searches. Typing this should behave the same as `[tagname]`, i.e. give results tagged with `tagname`.

This will need to be fixed in 2 places:

- If the tag is the only search term, it currently redirects to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagtagname`. Should instead redirect to `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tagname`.
- If the tag is one of multiple search terms, it goes to `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[tag%3Atagname]+foo`.

Comment: This should just be a part of your question. Considering it's a feature request, there should actually be a feature in your question that you're *requesting*.